# Open files in existing window in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-3

Currently, when I double-click on a file in Finder, it opens a *new* Sublime Text window, when I already have a Sublime Text window open. This results in me having to drag the tab in the *new* window to the *existing* window. If I use the File-->Open menu in Sublime Text, it, of course, opens in the same window.

I would like the *default behavior*, when opening a file in Finder, to open the file in the existing Sublime Text window. I scoured through the settings/preferences in Sublime Text, but I couldn't find anything related to what I want.

Is this behavior even possible? If so, how do I modify the preferences to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a macOS-only setting which does exactly that (taken from `Preferences.sublime-settings`):

```
// OS X only: When files are opened from finder, or by dragging onto the
// dock icon, this controls if a new window is created or not.
"open_files_in_new_window": true
```

When using the command-line, you can use the `-a` switch to append to an existing window:

`subl -a index.html`

The same switch could be used on Windows by modifying the default open action in the registry.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thanks for your answer!