# How to create a new project in Sublime Text 3, in a new projects tab, without closing other open projects?

Tags: sublime-text-3

**There's no 'New project' option in Sublime Text 3,** only options for doing things with existing projects:

[image]

I've seen various pages titled "How to create a project", but:

- [This gist gives a method](https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/e59659c26667a36dab29adab9425e109) that starts with 'Add folder to project', assumes you don't have any projects open. If you do, it adds the folder to an existing project
- [The suggested steps in this forum post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-create-projects/6860/5) start with closing all open projects
- [The unofficial docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/projects.html) also discuss "closing any active project with the Project → Close Project menu" or opening a new window

None of them seem to do what I want to do, which is:

- Create a new project I can add folders to,
- ...without closing all the other projects I have open,
- ...as a new tab in the same application window

...just like a "New project" menu item would. Is it possible, or do I have to close other projects or drag the tab back into the original window every time?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible like this:

- In Sublime, go to **File > New Window**, which creates a new Sublime window as a *tab* in the same *application window* (seems to consistently stay in the same application window regardless of [your `open_files_in_new_window` setting](https://superuser.com/questions/1272399/open-files-in-existing-window-in-sublime-text))

[image]

- **This new tab / window is treated as a new 'Anonymous project'**. So File > New Window is *effectively* the "New empty project" button missing from the Project menu.
- You can therefore add folders to it, save it, etc

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you have a project opened (as the OP does in his question), you can simply select Project -> Remove All Folders From Project which will net you a project with no open folders. Then follow the steps outlined in this post: https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/e59659c26667a36dab29adab9425e109

IMHO, it is preferable to open a new anonymous project from the beginning as mentioned by user56reinstatemonica8 above.